# vulkan problem when running Unrealeditor for the first time

Tags: graphics, vulkan, crash-reports, unreal-engine5

when i tried to run unrealeditor for the first time ,i see this crash on crash reporter window:

```
Fatal error: [File:./Runtime/VulkanRHI/Private/VulkanUtil.cpp] [Line: 931] VulkanRHI::vkCreateQueryPool(Device->GetInstanceHandle(), &PoolCreateInfo, VULKAN_CPU_ALLOCATOR, &QueryPool) failed, VkResult=-2 at ./Runtime/VulkanRHI/Private/VulkanQuery.cpp:58 with error VK_ERROR_OUT_OF_DEVICE_MEMORY 0x00007f4ae0753150 libUnrealEditor-VulkanRHI.so!void DispatchCheckVerify<void, VulkanRHI::VerifyVulkanResult(VkResult, char const*, char const*, unsigned int)::$_236, FLogCategoryLogVulkanRHI, char16_t [49], char16_t*, int, char16_t*, unsigned int, char16_t const*>(VulkanRHI::VerifyVulkanResult(VkResult, char const*, char const*, unsigned int)::$_236&&, FLogCategoryLogVulkanRHI const&, char16_t const (&) [49], char16_t* const&, int const&, char16_t* const&, unsigned int const&, char16_t const* const&) [/mnt/horde/++UE5/Sync/Engine/Source/Runtime/Core/Public/Misc/AssertionMacros.h:171] 0x00007f4ae05dec35 libUnrealEditor-VulkanRHI.so!VulkanRHI::VerifyVulkanResult(VkResult, char const*, char const*, unsigned int) [/mnt/horde/++UE5/Sync/Engine/Source/./Runtime/VulkanRHI/Private/VulkanUtil.cpp:930] 0x00007f4ae059fd45 libUnrealEditor-VulkanRHI.so!FVulkanQueryPool::FVulkanQueryPool(FVulkanDevice*, FVulkanCommandBufferManager*, unsigned int, VkQueryType, bool) [/mnt/horde/++UE5/Sync/Engine/Source/./Runtime/VulkanRHI/Private/VulkanQuery.cpp:58] 0x00007f4ae05ab63f libUnrealEditor-VulkanRHI.so!FVulkanRayTracingCompactionRequestHandler::FVulkanRayTracingCompactionRequestHandler(FVulkanDevice*) [/mnt/horde/++UE5/Sync/Engine/Source/./Runtime/VulkanRHI/Private/VulkanRayTracing.cpp:1192] 0x00007f4ae053e9f0 libUnrealEditor-VulkanRHI.so!FVulkanDevice::InitGPU() [/mnt/horde/++UE5/Sync/Engine/Source/./Runtime/VulkanRHI/Private/VulkanDevice.cpp:1136] 0x00007f4ae05dc690 libUnrealEditor-VulkanRHI.so!FVulkanDynamicRHI::InitInstance() [/mnt/horde/++UE5/Sync/Engine/Source/./Runtime/VulkanRHI/Private/VulkanRHI.cpp:753] 0x00007f4ae05dc361 libUnrealEditor-VulkanRHI.so!FVulkanDynamicRHI::Init() [/mnt/horde/++UE5/Sync/Engine/Source/./Runtime/VulkanRHI/Private/VulkanRHI.cpp:258] 0x00007f4b548ff96e libUnrealEditor-RHI.so!RHIInit(bool) [/mnt/horde/++UE5/Sync/Engine/Source/./Runtime/RHI/Private/DynamicRHI.cpp:340] 0x0000000000252410 UnrealEditor!FEngineLoop::PreInitPreStartupScreen(char16_t const*) [/mnt/horde/++UE5/Sync/Engine/Source/./Runtime/Launch/Private/LaunchEngineLoop.cpp:2818] 0x0000000000248c62 UnrealEditor!GuardedMain(char16_t const*) [/mnt/horde/++UE5/Sync/Engine/Source/./Runtime/Launch/Private/Launch.cpp:154] 0x00007f4b5bbc92d2 libUnrealEditor-UnixCommonStartup.so!CommonUnixMain(int, char**, int (*)(char16_t const*), void (*)()) [/mnt/horde/++UE5/Sync/Engine/Source/Runtime/Unix/UnixCommonStartup/Private/UnixCommonStartup.cpp:269] 0x00007f4b4fa29d90 libc.so.6!UnknownFunction(0x29d8f) 0x00007f4b4fa29e40 libc.so.6!__libc_start_main(+0x7f) 0x00000000002351b9 UnrealEditor!_start()

libUnrealEditor-VulkanRHI.so!VulkanRHI::VerifyVulkanResult(VkResult, char const*, char const*, unsigned int) [/mnt/horde/++UE5/Sync/Engine/Source/./Runtime/VulkanRHI/Private/VulkanUtil.cpp:930]
libUnrealEditor-VulkanRHI.so!FVulkanQueryPool::FVulkanQueryPool(FVulkanDevice*, FVulkanCommandBufferManager*, unsigned int, VkQueryType, bool) [/mnt/horde/++UE5/Sync/Engine/Source/./Runtime/VulkanRHI/Private/VulkanQuery.cpp:58]
libUnrealEditor-VulkanRHI.so!FVulkanRayTracingCompactionRequestHandler::FVulkanRayTracingCompactionRequestHandler(FVulkanDevice*) [/mnt/horde/++UE5/Sync/Engine/Source/./Runtime/VulkanRHI/Private/VulkanRayTracing.cpp:1192]
libUnrealEditor-VulkanRHI.so!FVulkanDevice::InitGPU() [/mnt/horde/++UE5/Sync/Engine/Source/./Runtime/VulkanRHI/Private/VulkanDevice.cpp:1136]
libUnrealEditor-VulkanRHI.so!FVulkanDynamicRHI::InitInstance() [/mnt/horde/++UE5/Sync/Engine/Source/./Runtime/VulkanRHI/Private/VulkanRHI.cpp:753]
libUnrealEditor-VulkanRHI.so!FVulkanDynamicRHI::Init() [/mnt/horde/++UE5/Sync/Engine/Source/./Runtime/VulkanRHI/Private/VulkanRHI.cpp:258]
libUnrealEditor-RHI.so!RHIInit(bool) [/mnt/horde/++UE5/Sync/Engine/Source/./Runtime/RHI/Private/DynamicRHI.cpp:340]
UnrealEditor!FEngineLoop::PreInitPreStartupScreen(char16_t const*) [/mnt/horde/++UE5/Sync/Engine/Source/./Runtime/Launch/Private/LaunchEngineLoop.cpp:2818]
UnrealEditor!GuardedMain(char16_t const*) [/mnt/horde/++UE5/Sync/Engine/Source/./Runtime/Launch/Private/Launch.cpp:154]
libUnrealEditor-UnixCommonStartup.so!CommonUnixMain(int, char**, int (*)(char16_t const*), void (*)()) [/mnt/horde/++UE5/Sync/Engine/Source/Runtime/Unix/UnixCommonStartup/Private/UnixCommonStartup.cpp:269]
libc.so.6!UnknownFunction(0x29d8f)
libc.so.6!__libc_start_main(+0x7f)
UnrealEditor!_start()
```

**and the most important lines that i see on terminal  :**

```
[2023.05.17-20.06.36:812][  0]LogInit: Initializing SDL.
[2023.05.17-20.06.36:979][  0]LogInit: Initialized SDL 2.0.20 revision:  (compiled against 2.0.20)
[2023.05.17-20.06.36:979][  0]LogInit: Using SDL video driver 'x11'
[2023.05.17-20.06.36:979][  0]LogInit: Display metrics:
[2023.05.17-20.06.36:979][  0]LogInit:   PrimaryDisplayWidth: 1360
[2023.05.17-20.06.36:979][  0]LogInit:   PrimaryDisplayHeight: 768
[2023.05.17-20.06.36:979][  0]LogInit:   PrimaryDisplayWorkAreaRect:
[2023.05.17-20.06.36:979][  0]LogInit:     Left=74, Top=27, Right=1360, Bottom=768
[2023.05.17-20.06.36:979][  0]LogInit:   VirtualDisplayRect:
[2023.05.17-20.06.36:979][  0]LogInit:     Left=74, Top=27, Right=1360, Bottom=768
[2023.05.17-20.06.36:979][  0]LogInit:   TitleSafePaddingSize: X=0.000 Y=0.000 Z=0.000 W=0.000
[2023.05.17-20.06.36:979][  0]LogInit:   ActionSafePaddingSize: X=0.000 Y=0.000 Z=0.000 W=0.000
[2023.05.17-20.06.36:979][  0]LogInit:   Number of monitors: 1
[2023.05.17-20.06.36:979][  0]LogInit:     Monitor 0
[2023.05.17-20.06.36:979][  0]LogInit:       Name: XWAYLAND0 14"
[2023.05.17-20.06.36:979][  0]LogInit:       ID: display0
[2023.05.17-20.06.36:979][  0]LogInit:       NativeWidth: 1360
[2023.05.17-20.06.36:979][  0]LogInit:       NativeHeight: 768
[2023.05.17-20.06.36:979][  0]LogInit:       bIsPrimary: true

[2023.05.17-20.06.38:580][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: Found 2 device(s)
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:580][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: Device 0:
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:580][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: - DeviceName: Intel(R) HD Graphics 520 (SKL GT2)
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:580][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: - API=1.3.250 (0x4030fa) Driver=0x5c01063 VendorId=0x8086
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:580][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: - DeviceID=0x1916 Type=VK_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_TYPE_INTEGRATED_GPU
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:580][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: - Max Descriptor Sets Bound 32, Timestamps 1
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:580][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: Device 1:

[2023.05.17-20.06.38:585][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Warning: 64bit image atomics were enabled, but the R64 format does not have UAV capabilities.  Disabling support.
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:585][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: Max memory allocations 4294967295.
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:585][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: 1 Device Memory Heaps:
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:585][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:   0: Flags 0x1 - Size 6156966912 (5871.74 MB) - Used 0 (0.00%) - DeviceLocal
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:585][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: 3 Device Memory Types (Not unified):
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:585][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:   0: Flags 0x00001 - Heap  0 - VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:585][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:   1: Flags 0x00007 - Heap  0 - VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT|VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT|VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:585][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:   2: Flags 0x0000f - Heap  0 - VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT|VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT|VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT|VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_CACHED_BIT
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:585][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: Memory Budget Extension:
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:585][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:             | Usage                     | Budget          | Size            |
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:585][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:    ---------|------------------------------------------------------------------|
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:585][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:     HEAP 00 |   0.00% /          0.00 MB |       4039.00 MB |       5871.74 MB |
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:585][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:    ---------|------------------------------------------------------------------|
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:600][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: FVulkanPipelineStateCacheManager: Binary pipeline cache '../../../../.config/Epic/UnrealEngine/5.1/Saved/VulkanPSO.cache.8086.1916' not found.
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:601][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Error: VulkanRHI::vkCreateQueryPool(Device->GetInstanceHandle(), &PoolCreateInfo, VULKAN_CPU_ALLOCATOR, &QueryPool) failed, VkResult=-2
 at ./Runtime/VulkanRHI/Private/VulkanQuery.cpp:58 
 with error VK_ERROR_OUT_OF_DEVICE_MEMORY
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:601][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: /******************************************* Device Memory ********************************************\
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:601][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: Max memory allocations 4294967295.
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:601][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: 1 Device Memory Heaps:
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:601][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:   0: Flags 0x1 - Size 6156966912 (5871.74 MB) - Used 71303168 (1.16%) - DeviceLocal
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:601][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: 3 Device Memory Types (Not unified):
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:601][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:   0: Flags 0x00001 - Heap  0 - VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:601][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:   1: Flags 0x00007 - Heap  0 - VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT|VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT|VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:601][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:   2: Flags 0x0000f - Heap  0 - VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT|VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT|VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT|VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_CACHED_BIT
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:601][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: Memory Budget Extension:
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:601][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:             | Usage                     | Budget          | Size            |
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:601][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:    ---------|------------------------------------------------------------------|
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:601][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:     HEAP 00 |   0.00% /          0.00 MB |       4039.00 MB |       5871.74 MB |
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:601][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:    ---------|------------------------------------------------------------------|
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:601][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: Device Memory: 6 allocations on 1 heaps
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:601][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:    Heap 0, 6 allocations
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:601][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:        Alloc AllocSize(MB) TotalSize(MB)    Handle
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:601][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:            0         4.000         0.000 0x2e37410
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:601][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:            1         4.000         4.000 0x2e37570
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:601][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:            2         4.000         8.000 0x2e374c0
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:601][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:            3        32.000        12.000 0x2e376d0
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:601][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:            4        16.000        44.000 0x2e37780
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:601][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:            5         8.000        60.000 0x2e3bfe0
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:601][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:        Total Allocated 68.00 MB, Peak 68.00 MB
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:601][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: Blocks Kept alive Current Frame (1) 
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:601][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: Free Blocks in Allocations:
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:601][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: /******************************************* FMemoryManager ********************************************\
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:601][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: HEAP DUMP
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:601][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: ResourceHeap 0, Memory Type Index 0
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:601][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:        ActivePages0:(  0.01mb/  8.00mb) ID    0    1 suballocs,    1 free chunks,DeviceMemory 0x2e3bfe0
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:601][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: ResourceHeap 1, Memory Type Index 1
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:601][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:        ActivePages0:(  0.00mb/ 32.00mb) ID    0    1 suballocs,    1 free chunks,DeviceMemory 0x2e376d0
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:601][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: ResourceHeap 2, Memory Type Index 2
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:601][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: BUFFER DUMP
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:601][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: Buffer of 128 size Allocations: 0 Used / 0 Free
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:601][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: Buffer of 256 size Allocations: 0 Used / 0 Free
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:601][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: Buffer of 512 size Allocations: 0 Used / 0 Free
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:601][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: Buffer of 1024 size Allocations: 0 Used / 0 Free
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:601][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: Buffer of 2048 size Allocations: 0 Used / 0 Free
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:601][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: Buffer of 8192 size Allocations: 0 Used / 0 Free
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:601][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: Buffer of 0 size Allocations: 0 Used / 0 Free
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:601][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: Buffer of large size Allocations: 4 Used / 0 Free
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:601][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: Index  BufferHandle       DeviceMemoryHandle MemFlags BufferFlags #Suballocs #FreeChunks UsedSize/MaxSize
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:601][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:      0 0x0000000002de8490 0x0000000002e37410 0x000006 0x000000f5      1        0        4194304/4194304
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:601][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:      1 0x0000000002e42d70 0x0000000002e37570 0x000006 0x000000f5      1        0        4194304/4194304
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:601][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:      2 0x0000000002de8500 0x0000000002e374c0 0x000006 0x000000f5      1        0        4194304/4194304
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:601][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:      3 0x0000000002df0060 0x0000000002e37780 0x000006 0x00000010      1        0        16777216/16777216
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:601][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:  Large Alloc Used/Max 29360128/29360128 100.00%
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:601][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: ::Totals::
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:601][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: Large Alloc Used/Max 29360128/29360128 100.00%
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:601][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: Binned Alloc Used/Max 0/0 0.00%
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:601][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: SUMMARY
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:601][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:        Device Heaps                       |    Memory       Reserved      FreeMem       TotalMem   |  Allocs     -         |  Allocs              | Flags | Type   
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:601][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:        ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:601][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:        Device Heap 0                      |   68.00mb /     0.00mb /     5803.74mb /     5871.74mb |          6          0 |      6      0      0 | 0000f | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT|VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT|VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT|VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_CACHED_BIT
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:601][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:        ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:601][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:        ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:601][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:        Allocators                         |    BufMem       ImgMem        FreeMem       TotalMem   |  BufAllocs  ImgAllocs |  Pages BufPgs ImgPgs | Flags | Type   
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:601][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:        ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:601][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:        ResourceHeap 0                     |    0.00mb /     0.01mb /        7.99mb /        8.00mb |          0          1 |      1      0      1 | 00001 | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:601][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:        ResourceHeap 1                     |    0.00mb /     0.00mb /       32.00mb /       32.00mb |          0          1 |      1      0      1 | 00007 | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT|VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT|VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:602][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:        ResourceHeap 2                     |    0.00mb /     0.00mb /        0.00mb /        0.00mb |          0          0 |      0      0      0 | 0000f | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT|VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT|VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT|VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_CACHED_BIT
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:602][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:        ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:602][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:        Pool 128                           |    0.00mb /     0.00mb /        0.00mb /        0.00mb |          0          0 |      0      0      0 | 00000 | Unhandled VkMemoryPropertyFlagBits
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:602][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:        Pool 256                           |    0.00mb /     0.00mb /        0.00mb /        0.00mb |          0          0 |      0      0      0 | 00000 | Unhandled VkMemoryPropertyFlagBits
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:602][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:        Pool 512                           |    0.00mb /     0.00mb /        0.00mb /        0.00mb |          0          0 |      0      0      0 | 00000 | Unhandled VkMemoryPropertyFlagBits
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:602][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:        Pool 1024                          |    0.00mb /     0.00mb /        0.00mb /        0.00mb |          0          0 |      0      0      0 | 00000 | Unhandled VkMemoryPropertyFlagBits
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:602][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:        Pool 2048                          |    0.00mb /     0.00mb /        0.00mb /        0.00mb |          0          0 |      0      0      0 | 00000 | Unhandled VkMemoryPropertyFlagBits
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:602][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:        Pool 8192                          |    0.00mb /     0.00mb /        0.00mb /        0.00mb |          0          0 |      0      0      0 | 00000 | Unhandled VkMemoryPropertyFlagBits
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:602][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:        Pool 0                             |    0.00mb /     0.00mb /        0.00mb /        0.00mb |          0          0 |      0      0      0 | 00000 | Unhandled VkMemoryPropertyFlagBits
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:602][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:        Pool -1                            |    0.00mb /     0.00mb /        0.00mb /        0.00mb |          0          0 |      0      0      0 | 00000 | Unhandled VkMemoryPropertyFlagBits
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:602][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:        ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:602][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:        Pool 128                           |    0.00mb /     0.00mb /        0.00mb /        0.00mb |          0          0 |      0      0      0 | 00000 | Unhandled VkMemoryPropertyFlagBits
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:602][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:        Pool 256                           |    0.00mb /     0.00mb /        0.00mb /        0.00mb |          0          0 |      0      0      0 | 00000 | Unhandled VkMemoryPropertyFlagBits
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:602][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:        Pool 512                           |    0.00mb /     0.00mb /        0.00mb /        0.00mb |          0          0 |      0      0      0 | 00000 | Unhandled VkMemoryPropertyFlagBits
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:602][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:        Pool 1024                          |    0.00mb /     0.00mb /        0.00mb /        0.00mb |          0          0 |      0      0      0 | 00000 | Unhandled VkMemoryPropertyFlagBits
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:602][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:        Pool 2048                          |    0.00mb /     0.00mb /        0.00mb /        0.00mb |          0          0 |      0      0      0 | 00000 | Unhandled VkMemoryPropertyFlagBits
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:602][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:        Pool 8192                          |    0.00mb /     0.00mb /        0.00mb /        0.00mb |          0          0 |      0      0      0 | 00000 | Unhandled VkMemoryPropertyFlagBits
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:602][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:        Pool 0                             |    0.00mb /     0.00mb /        0.00mb /        0.00mb |          0          0 |      0      0      0 | 00000 | Unhandled VkMemoryPropertyFlagBits
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:602][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:        Pool -1                            |   28.00mb /     0.00mb /        0.00mb /       28.00mb |          4          0 |      4      4      0 | 00006 | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT|VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:602][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:        ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:602][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:        Dedicated Pages                    |    0.00mb /     0.00mb /        0.00mb /        0.00mb |          0          0 |      0      0      0 | 00000 | Unhandled VkMemoryPropertyFlagBits
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:602][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:        ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:602][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:        TotalHost                          |   28.00mb /     0.00mb /        0.00mb /       28.00mb |          4          0 |      4      4      0 | 00006 | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT|VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:602][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:        TotalLocal                         |    0.00mb /     0.01mb /       39.99mb /       40.00mb |          0          2 |      2      0      2 | 0000f | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT|VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT|VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT|VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_CACHED_BIT
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:602][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:        Total                              |   28.00mb /     0.01mb /       39.99mb /       68.00mb |          4          2 |      6      4      2 | 00000 | Unhandled VkMemoryPropertyFlagBits
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:602][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:        ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:602][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:        Allocated Device Heap 0            |   28.00mb /     0.01mb /     5843.73mb /     5871.74mb |          4          2 |      6      4      2 | 0000f | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT|VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT|VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT|VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_CACHED_BIT
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:602][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:        ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:602][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:        Subsystems                         |    BufMem       ImgMem        FreeMem       TotalMem   |  BufAllocs  ImgAllocs |  Pages BufPgs ImgPgs | Flags | Type   
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:602][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:        ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:602][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:        Staging                            |    0.00mb /     0.00mb /        0.00mb /        0.00mb |          1          0 |      0      0      0 | 00006 | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT|VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:602][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:        ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:602][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display: 

SubAllocator Dump


[2023.05.17-20.06.38:602][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:        ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:602][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:                                                       | Free    Count | Fill /       Used /       Free /      Total /    Largest |    Unknown /        UBO /   MultiBuf /  FrameTemp |    ImageRT /      Image |  BufferUAV /  BufferStg /    BufOthr |
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:602][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:        ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:602][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:        Page[I ] - ResTypeHeaps[0] ActivePages[0] [   5]  |    1        1 |   0% /     0.01mb /     7.99mb /     8.00mb /     7.99mb |     0.00mb /     0.00mb /     0.00mb /     0.00mb |     0.01mb /     0.00mb |     0.00mb /     0.00mb /     0.00mb | 0 0 | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:603][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:        Page[IB] - ResTypeHeaps[1] ActivePages[0] [   3]  |    1        1 |   0% /     0.00mb /    32.00mb /    32.00mb /    32.00mb |     0.00mb /     0.00mb /     0.00mb /     0.00mb |     0.00mb /     0.00mb |     0.00mb /     0.00mb /     0.00mb | 1 0 | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT|VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT|VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:603][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:        ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:603][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:        PoolUsed 7 [   0]                              |    0        1 | 100% /     4.00mb /     0.00mb /     4.00mb /     0.00mb |     0.00mb /     0.00mb /     0.00mb /     4.00mb |     0.00mb /     0.00mb |     0.00mb /     0.00mb /     0.00mb | 1 0 | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT|VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:603][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:        PoolUsed 7 [   1]                              |    0        1 | 100% /     4.00mb /     0.00mb /     4.00mb /     0.00mb |     0.00mb /     0.00mb /     0.00mb /     4.00mb |     0.00mb /     0.00mb |     0.00mb /     0.00mb /     0.00mb | 1 0 | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT|VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:603][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:        PoolUsed 7 [   2]                              |    0        1 | 100% /     4.00mb /     0.00mb /     4.00mb /     0.00mb |     0.00mb /     0.00mb /     0.00mb /     4.00mb |     0.00mb /     0.00mb |     0.00mb /     0.00mb /     0.00mb | 1 0 | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT|VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:603][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:        PoolUsed 7 [   4]                              |    0        1 | 100% /    16.00mb /     0.00mb /    16.00mb /     0.00mb |     0.00mb /     0.00mb /     0.00mb /     0.00mb |     0.00mb /     0.00mb |     0.00mb /     0.00mb /     0.00mb | 1 0 | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT|VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT
[2023.05.17-20.06.38:603][  0]LogVulkanRHI: Display:        ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
context
```

my device charachtersitc is :RAM:8,0 GiB,PROCESSOR:intel® Core™ i5-6300U CPU @ 2.40GHz × 4
GRAPHICS:Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 520 (SKL GT2).

i have two questions:

1-why this error happened,and how to fix it?

2-can i use other api like opengl instead of vulkan for unrealEngine

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Looks like it shows two devices and the second device is some kind of nonsense.

Comment: This seems on unreal forums: https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/driver-error-please-help-me/1162248

Comment: yeah,i see that post ,no help.if you already familiar with unreal engine does it works with intel graphics or it need nvidia graphics card,and does i can use an api with unreal engine instead of vulkan?

Comment: i think my vram is 256M,but unreal engine need 8GO in VRAM as i think this is the problem,does i can do something for fix that(i can't upgrade my gpu),or is there an other c++ engine that i can use instead of unreal engine

Comment: Integrated GPU is not great in terms of performance, and historically not even in driver quality. The log says it fails on creating Query Pool, which might be sort of a different limit from just raw memory amount. What is weird in your log though, the memory types shown seem inconsistent with the GPU you say you have. It could also be some mishap with switchable graphics, or with driver install in general.